# "A volume with software packages has been detected. Would you like to open it with the package manager?"

Tags: 16.04, live-usb

I use Ubuntu 14.04 on my desktop. I am considering upgrading to 16.04 so I looked at [Create a bootable USB stick on Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0). I downloaded a 16.04 iso file and then used Startup Disk Creator to create a bootable 16.04 USB stick.

Part way through the process I received a message: "A volume with software packages has been detected. Would you like to open it with the package manager?"

This worried me as I thought it may install 16.04 on my hard disk and not on the USB so I aborted the process.

Will answering "yes" install 16.04 on my hard disk?

Comment: @mikewhatever It's related, but not a duplicate. OP here is asking what to do when it comes up once, OP there is asking why it keeps coming up. And if OP here follows the advice of the answer on the duplicate and ejects the flash drive, it might interrupt creating the live USB.

Answer (score 1):

No, answering Yes will not install 16.04, but will add the USB to the sources.list as another repository. That's not what you want, so don't answer Yes. Let the USB creator do its job until completion.